# make current and future elements draggable

Tags: draggable

I have a little web application in which I create DIVs by clicking on a button. I would like to make these created DIVs draggable, so I did a little research, and read about the "livequery" plugin which is now unavailable.

Is there a solution for my problem ?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [LiveQuery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)